# How do I properly include external headers in Makefile using mingw32-make?

Tags: c++, makefile, build, mingw32

Two years ago I used to work with this Makefile:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Ic:/Program\ Files/JACK2/includes -Wall -std=c++1z
LDFLAGS= -Lc:/Program\ Files/JACK2/lib -llibjack
SOURCE= main.o jack_module.o

example: $(SOURCE)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS) $(SOURCE) $(LDFLAGS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

clean:
    rm -f example *.o
```

This Makefile would compile my custom audio program to connect with Jack audio. Now a couple years later (and not documented) the code is no longer compiling using `make` in mingw32.
I am using Windows 10, when I compile my code using `make` I get the following error message:

```
*****@DESKTOP-FM8BR6P MINGW64 /c/temp/HKU/CSD_2021/csd2b/theorie/session4/03_soundingSineClass (master)
$ make
g++ -c -Ic:/Program\ Files/JACK2/includes -Wall -std=c++1z main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
jack_module.h:13:23: fatal error: jack/jack.h: No such file or directory
 #include <jack/jack.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'main.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

My files are contained all withing one single folder and the folder where I try to include Jack2 is located in my "Program Files" folder.
Where the error seems to be occuring in `main.o`, it is actually because I am including another header (`jack_module.h`) file which contains the `#include` part where the error occurs:

```
#ifndef _JACK_MODULE_H_
#define _JACK_MODULE_H_

#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <jack/jack.h>
```

The first few lines of the `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "jack_module.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "sine.h"
```

I am curious to see what could be the issue for this error.

Comment: Does this file exist `c:/Program Files/JACK2/includes/jack/jack.h`

Comment: You may want to add to `CXXFLAGS` `-H` (to see which files are included from where) and `-v` to see what include paths are considered.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes this file does indeed exists, I have tripple checked it and reinstalled the SDK. For some reason it seems that make is not capable to include this path...

Comment: Figured out the error. Since Jack2 binaries have been updated over September and October I was working on an older version where the "includes" folder contained an "s". The new binairies use "include" without an "s" in the folder name. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes ya'll! Fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the error. Since Jack2 binaries have been updated over September and October I was working on an older version where the "includes" folder contained an "s". The new binairies use "include" without an "s" in the folder name. Thanks for the extra pair of eyes ya'll! Fixed the issue